# What is a simple visualization tool to show word counts?

Tags: r, graphics, nlp, data-visualization

I have a text file which has the count of how many times does a phrase appear inside a corpus. The file looks like this, with the phrase and its count separated by "=":

```
phrase1=100
phrase2=156
... and so on
```

What is a good simple visualization tool that can take this file (or a slightly modified version of this), and provide me a nice visualization in form of bubbles, where the bubble size is proportional to the count of the phrase. I would prefer the phrase be written inside the bubble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of plot you referred to in the OP (*bubble plot*) is also referred to as a *balloon plot*.

The title of your question is directed to the more general problem of intuitively displaying word frequency in a given text. Given this, perhaps it's worth mentioning that the infographics gurus are [critical of bubble plots](https://www.vis4.net/blog/2009/12/mapping-data-to-circles/) because the plot is based on *mapping data values to circle areas*.

Unfortunately, the same gurus haven't agreed on a plausible set of alternatives (as far as i know).

The best alternative to a bubble plot to show term frequency, that i can think of, is usually referred to as a ***tag cloud***.

On his blog, [Statistics, R, Graphics, and Fun](http://yihui.name/en/2009/06/creating-tag-cloud-using-r-and-flash-javascript-swfobject/), Yihui Xie, has written an excellent tutorial for creating tag clouds using R. His tutorial is excellent for two reasons--it's nicely written with step-by-step code, and the result is beautiful.

See also [this Post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/building-a-better-word-cloud/) on R Bloggers for a tutorial on creating a better tag cloud.

But if a bubble (aka balloon) plot is what you want, here you go.

They are simple to create in R. There is meticulously detailed step-by-step [*tutorial*](https://flowingdata.com/2010/11/23/how-to-make-bubble-charts/) for creating and polishing Bubble Charts on the excellent [Flow Data site](http://www.flowingdata.com).

In addition, the R Package ***gplots*** (available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/)) includes a function *balloonplot* for plotting these directly.

From the Flowing Data Site:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hum, I am not sure I completely understand you idea of Bubble graphics. For a lot of phrases it does not look feasible to me. Have you looked at [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)?

I have done similar project to count the words in Wikipedia:

[image: Wikipedia Frequency List]

The best way I know is to use double log scale. You can probably add some phrases on the graph. I created all graphics [here](http://imonad.com/seo/wikipedia-word-frequency-list/) with [Xmgrace](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/).

Comment: Thanks Ross for your reply. By Bubble graphics, I actually meant this:  http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bubble.html which shows bubbles and the radius of the bubble in my case should be propotional to the word count written inside the text.

Comment: Ok, then. If you know how to pack all the circles it can be easy to just generate SVG file with simple porgamm, then open it in Inkscape and generate PNG for example.

Comment: Concur with Ross' comment: for real-life NLP work, the proposed visualization is not going to be helpful.  You are going to have a lot of long-tail data (Zipf distribution), i.e. minimal bubbles with little impact on your overall understanding of your problem, and producing a graph for anything beyond toy data is going to require inordinate amounts of processing time.  But perhaps your problem is very specialized, so that you have no more than a few hundred labels? Perhaps you could clarify your usage scenario? But technically, GraphViz / dotty should be fine for this.

Comment: Yes, the number of final entires in the histogram file representing the text is minimal because I extract only those phrases that are noun-phrases along with their frequencies.